# How to find high values in the correlation matrix?

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation, cross-correlation, pearson-correlation

How can I return high similarities (or top correlation values, or values above a threshold) in the `correlation matrix`? For example, in the below example A1 and A3 have high correlation.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''Sentence, A1, A2, A3
                        text, 0.23, 0.54, 39
                        text, 0.33, 0.7, 36
                        text, 0.8, 0.41, 29'''), sep=',')
print(df.corr())
```

Result:

```
           A1        A2        A3
 A1  1.000000 -0.732859 -0.991352
 A2 -0.732859  1.000000  0.637235
 A3 -0.991352  0.637235  1.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing the example and using numpy:

```
c = df.corr()
import numpy as np

threshold = .99
np.abs(c.values) > threshold
```

This gives:

```
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

You can get the indices of the significant values which are off-diagonal via:

```
[(i, j) for i,j in zip(*np.where(np.abs(c.values) > threshold)) if i!=j]
```

This gives:

```
[(0, 2), (2, 0)]
```

**Update:**

Making use of the symmetry of the correlation matrix and one can get a list of readable strings with the column names:

```
[f"{c.columns[i]} and {c.columns[j]}" for i, j in zip(*np.where(np.abs(c.values) > threshold)) if i < j]
```

->

```
[' A1 and  A3']
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the feature space is large, it's a little hard to read. Is it possible to get column names?

Answer (score 1):

if you need the pairs with higest correlation then you need to stack then find the pairs with highest by stack this is the way

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''Sentence, A1, A2, A3
                        text, 0.23, 0.54, 39
                        text, 0.33, 0.7, 36
                        text, 0.8, 0.41, 29'''), sep=',')

df.drop(['Sentence'],1, inplace=True)
print(df.corr())


def get_red_pair(df):
    pairs_to_drop = set()
    cols = df.columns
    for i in range(0, df.shape[1]):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            pairs_to_drop.add((cols[i], cols[j]))
    return pairs_to_drop

def get_largest_correlations(df, n=5):
    au_corr = df.corr().abs().unstack()
    labels_to_drop = get_red_pair(df)
    au_corr = au_corr.drop(labels=labels_to_drop).sort_values(ascending=False)
    return au_corr[0:n]

corr = get_largest_correlations(df)
print(corr)
```

to get only the first one, then to the function make sure you pass n as 1 because by default it expect 5

if this is not what you are looking for then framing your question well might help

this gives

```
           A1        A2        A3
 A1  1.000000 -0.732859 -0.991352
 A2 -0.732859  1.000000  0.637235
 A3 -0.991352  0.637235  1.000000

 A1   A3    0.991352
      A2    0.732859
 A2   A3    0.637235
```